# What are the three equations for this problem? (system of 3 variables)

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

A cashier has a total of 30 bills, made up of ones, fives, and twenties. The number of twenties is 9 more than the number of ones. The total value of the money is $351. How many of each denomination of bills are there? (Hint: Let x = the number of ones, y = the number of fives, and z = the number of twenties)

I'm having a hard time figuring out the three equations for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start with these equations:

$$z = x+9$$

$$20z+5y+x=351$$

$$z+y+x = 30$$

And plug in the first equation in the second until you can solve for one variable, the rest should come easy.